# Вывести название в метку карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

вывожу карту и нужно сделать вывод название города в метку на карту, пробовал так `iconContent: 'Нижний Новгород'` но ничего

вывод карты с метками

```
<script>
    ymaps.ready(function () {

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
             center: [53.902257, 27.561831],
            zoom: 6
        },
        {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),


    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {

            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки'

        });

var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode("[[+city]][[+adress]]");
myGeocoder.then(
    function (res) {
        myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects.get(0));

    },
    function (err) {
        // обработка ошибки
    }
);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть [готовый пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode) с решением Вашей задачи. Лучше устанавливать опции метки при геокодировании, вот так:

```
 ymaps.geocode('Нижний Новгород', {
        results: 1
    }).then(function (res) {
            // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования.
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                // Координаты геообъекта.
                coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                // Область видимости геообъекта.
                bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');

            firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
            // Получаем строку с адресом и выводим в иконке геообъекта.
            firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());

            // Добавляем первый найденный геообъект на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
            // Масштабируем карту на область видимости геообъекта.
            myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
                // Проверяем наличие тайлов на данном масштабе.
                checkZoomRange: true
            });
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/211894)

Comment: спасибо, исправила